# proper syntax for generating JSON body in API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

With the following long controller action code

```
@available = Available.find(694)
@tareservation_id = 8943
@request_date_time = Time.now.utc.iso8601
@request_id = Time.now.to_i
@in_date = (Date.today + 24.days).strftime("%Y-%m-%d").to_s
@book = %Q|{ 
  "booking": {
    "currencyCode": "USD",  
    "languageCode": "es",  
    "paxNationality": "ES",
    "clientRef": {
      "value": \"#{@tareservation_id}\",
      "mustBeUnique": true
    },
    "items": [
      {
        "itemNumber": 1,
        "immediateConfirmationRequired": true,
        "productCode": \"#{@available.product_code}\",
        "leadPaxName": 
          { "firstName": "Guy", 
            "lastName": "Test"
          },
        "product": 
          {
            "period": 
            {
              "start": "2018-08-27",
              "quantity": 2
            }
          }
        } ]
  },
  "requestAuditInfo": 
    { "agentCode": "001", 
      "requestPassword": "pass",
      "requestDateTime":  \"#{@requestDateTime}\",  
      "requestID": #{@request_id}    }, 
  "versionNumber": "2.0"
  }|
```

This then must be shipped off to the API as JSON in the body call

```
@result = HTTParty.post(
  'https://test.com/search', 
  :body => JSON.parse(@book).to_json,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Connection' => 'Keep-Alive'
  }
)
```

If the following block is removed:

```
        ,
        "product": 
          {
            "period": 
            {
              "start": "2018-08-27",
              "quantity": 2
            }
          }
```

in console `JSON.parse(@start)`, parses properly. With the block `JSON::ParserError: 784: unexpected token`.  Yet I fail to see what is incorrect here?

Is Rails handling of string for future JSON conversion really strict on syntax, particularly since there is interpretation of instance variables - both as strings and integers - and har returns involved? What would it be then?  Or is there a safer solution to get out of what quickly becomes quicksand?

Comment: Check whether the JSON is valid or not in online JSON validator .

Comment: Yes, the JSON  validates with direct string or integer data.  So why does `JSON.parse` go flaky?

Comment: Why don't use Jbuilder template to create the JSON?

Comment: That is a thought. First I am trying to understand why rails' JSON parsing is choking on apparently proper data.  Secondly, I've used jbuilder mainly from views.  Provide an example from above in controller context for acceptance/voting.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that pasting too many lines into the console (iTerm2, in this case) does something to the memory.  25 lines of code pasted in a single time is the maximum observered where behaviour is as expected.